# MS Access subform text boxes input by query. Can I add default values?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am trying to auto fill in text/check boxes. I only want to do this when a button is pressed. Currently the form detail in design view has 1 row of text/check boxes (pic 1), when the query is run in form view it creates 19 more items in the column (pic 2).

I can fill in the first line by just entering amount.value="99999" but the rest of the 'boxes' aren't there so I can't add a value to them...
Am I able to add default values to these only when a button is pressed?

[image: design view]

[image: form view]

```
Private Sub Command23_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command23_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "InsertParaTypes"

    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

Exit_Command23_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command23_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command23_Click
```

Comment: Where is the button? You want every record to get the same value of `99999`? Use an UPDATE action SQL. Or loop RecordsetClone and set value of each record. Or code physically sets focus on each record in form and sets Value. Edit question to post code.

Comment: Yes, every record to get "99999" and the first 3 checkboxes "checked". BUT ONLY when a separate button is pressed. This button just populates the list

Comment: What does OpenQuery do - INSERT records? So in button event run UPDATE on those new records. What would be the filter criteria - a date or particular field Is Null?

Comment: Yes, they insert into. No filter criteria... I'm currently learning SQL so my knowledge is at a basic/novice level. this is the current code:
`INSERT INTO paradetails ( ptype, amount, paraid, class, emp )
SELECT ParaTypes.autoid, [enter maximum per disicipline] AS amount, paraheader.autoid, paraheader.class, paraheader.EMP
FROM ParaTypes, paraheader
WHERE (((paraheader.autoid)=[forms]![paraheader]![autoid]));`

Comment: Now build an UPDATE query that targets those new records. What would distinguish them from other existing records? The amount field Is Null and/or a date? Only you know what criteria can be used to select those new records - probably the same criteria that filters them for display on form.

Comment: You think an UPDATE query would be best? I'd have to add in through my VBA button (I have VBA>SQL statements so I can do it)

Comment: It is simpler code than looping through recordset.